# swf not working in IE when using https

Tags: internet-explorer, https, flash

I'm using a flash mp3 player (www.premiumbeat.com) within my website (localhost:8084 - tomcat). This is my situation:

- In my site I have secure files (any file under `/mywebapp/secure`) and public files (everything outside `/mywebapp/secure`). Secure files are served through https (port 8443)
- the mp3 player is located at: `/mywebapp/swf/player.swf` (public access).
- I'm using swfobject to insert with javascript code the mp3 player swf object into the page (swfobject is at: `/mywebapp/js/swfobject.js` public access).
- The webpage that uses the player is located at: `/mywebapp/secure/playerSample.html`
- The mp3 player gets a xml with list of tracks (the player request the list) from servlet `/mywebapp/servlet/playlist`

When I browse `playerSample.html` with firefox everything works just fine... I login into my webapp, access `playerSample.html` and the player shows the list of tracks retrieved from `/mywebapp/servlet/playlist`.

But when I browse the page with IE the list is not retrieved :S I have tested the code in parts and it works, for example, if I just call /mywebapp/servlet/playlist from a IE's window, I can get the xml track list from the servlet. And playerSample.html can show the flash mp3 player. It's the player which can't get the response from the servlet (or at least that's what looks like).

Why it's just happening on IE? I know IE sometimes just sucks... but, any ideas or work-arounds?

Answer (score 2):

Try monitoring your network traffic using Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com)  Be sure to enable HTTPS decryption, and trust the Fiddler root certificate.

Comment: Thank you, the https enablement and root cert part were what I was missing.