# SWF not playing in IE over https?

Tags: ssl, https, flash

this been driving me mad all day.

I export a swf/html direct from flash, very simple. I upload it and it works fine in all browsers. If I change http to https in all browsers, no problems.

All browsers except IE - when I change http to https, I just get nothing - if I right click I get "Movie not loaded..." (greyed out) and the usual about flash player.

I've reinstalled my flash player, read loads of tips and tried loads of other hacks but nothing seems to work.

I am using IE 9 (for testing only)

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code?

```
<div id="flashContent">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="562" height="300" id="banner" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="banner.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner.swf" width="562" height="300">
                <param name="movie" value="banner.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to HTTP headers that are sent by a web server in response to a request from a browser.

In IE specifically, any HTTP responses sent from a secure to an insecure context are ignored. It fails silently.

To get around this and allow HTTP responses to be received over SSL from a server, it is necessary to change the configuration at the web server level or set the headers at a code level to ensure that the proper headers are being sent with HTTP responses.

That HTTP header is as follows:  `Cache-Control: no-store`

I hope this answer helps to sort out your problem.
Source of my information: [Here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-flash-ssl-ie-wtf.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Before I start hassling the host, I tried adding: <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="no-Store"><META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT=""> - I also tried <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT=""><META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT=""> - in the head of the page. Should this work? Or does it need to be done at server level? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: UPDATE - well, I got the host to change those settings twice, tested both and didn't work. Also tried putting it in the meta tags. Strange thing is, on my gf IE it works fine. Just not on my IE. Could I have something stupid running on my IE or something?

Comment: UPDATE - ok assuming my host has done things right, still not working. Some minor progress, I found out if I enable (check) do not save encrypted pages to disk in IE/tools/advanced, it will not work, but if I uncheck it, it will work fine. Can't expect users to go wading around in settings, anything I can do at the server / code end? Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973727/swf-https-problem-with-ie

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this problem for a while.
I found an answer on Adobe site (it works for me) http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-issues-secure-sockets.html#main_Data_Lloading_fails_when_using_a_no_cache_header_Pragma.

Hope it helps!